# ArcGIS RuntimeError: Not signed into Portal

Tags: arcgis, portal

I'm running ArcGIS Pro Python IDLE and getting an error that says: RuntimeError: Not signed into Portal.

I looked at my ArcGIS administrator to make sure my license was not expired and it isn't. This is a concurrent use license for ArcGIS Desktop through my university. I've never had this problem before.

```
#import modules
import arcpy
import os

#set working directory
folderpath = os.getcwd()

#set the arcpy envs
arcpy.env.workspace = folderpath
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = "Round2_5.shp"

#Create a list of fields using the ListFields function
fields = arcpy.ListFields(feature_class)

#Iterate through the list of fields
for field in fields:

arcpy.SpatialAutocorrelation_stats(fc, field, "REPORT","INVERSE_DISTANCE",
                                   "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE", "NONE")

 #The full error message:    
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\Global Health Job\GIS\2_5_Spatial_Auto.py", 
line 8, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 72, in 
<module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", 
 line 14, in <module>
    from ._base import *
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 
 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
 RuntimeError: Not signed into Portal.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using the ArcGIS Pro Python Interpreter. This interpreter needs to be logged on Portal or ArcGIS Online if a named user license is configured.

I realized you use ArcMap libraries in your script.

In that case, try to execute your Python Script using the ArcMap Interpreter located in `C:\Python27`